# How to use var.get in JDBC in Jmeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I have a question about jdbc in jmeter,
I have a value (employee), that I want to check if it exists in a list. 
i try to perform a query to DB and to use var.get function, is it possible?
it only worked when I use ${value}. is it possible to use var.get?

in the test I try to perform call and check if employee exists in test_case_string_employee.

```
select count (*)
from employee
where CreatedAtDate ='today'
and employee IN ${test_case_string_employee};
```

the code is working. but can I change what is after the "IN"?

I tried

```
IN 'vars.get("test_case_string_employee")';
```

and

```
IN vars.get("test_case_string_employee");
```

and got exceptions 
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vars.get only works in scripting elements (jsr223, beanshell).

In other test elements, you need to use:

> ${}

Answer (score 0):

1. As per [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) documentation chapter:

   > Variables are referenced as follows:

   > ```
   >  ${VARIABLE}
   > ```
2. As per [SQL IN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) tutorial your query seems to be missing parentheses and quotation marks

So my expectation is that you need to amend your query like:

```
select count (*) 
from employee
where CreatedAtDate ='today'
and employee IN ('${test_case_string_employee}');
```

---

If you prefer `vars` shorthand you can do the same using [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like:

```
select count (*) 
from employee
where CreatedAtDate ='today'
and employee IN ('${__groovy(vars.get('test_case_string_employee'),)}');
```

however it might be an overkill for particularly this scenario.